# Process.Start() throwing intermittent "No application is associated.." on .DOC files

Tags: .net, ms-word, explorer, windows-shell

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() is throwing intermittent System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No application is associated with the specified file for this operation.

The file is a .doc file.
They are always able to open it manually (double-click).

What could be the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect that the file association on your system is somewhat broken.

Open Windows Explorer, and check what is defined under Tools->Folder Options->File Types->DOC->Advanced->Open->Edit.

You should have the following values:

- Action: &Open
- Application (adjust the path accordingly): "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE" /n /dde
- Use DDE must be checked

  - DDE Message: [REM _DDE_Direct][FileOpen("%1")]
  - Application: WinWord
  - DDE Application (no value):
  - Topic: System

It might be that there is no *Advanced* button on the *File Types* dialog when DOC is selected, and that instead a *Restore* button is present. This is the case if a user has manually changed the file association using the *Open With...* option from the context menu of .doc files. Try if clicking on restore solves your problem.